# Angular app getting error as `Bash exited with code '134'.` on deploy to server

Tags: angular, angular8

When i deploy my application to server, I am getting an error as follow: any one help me to sort this?

```
 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x2cf31bbcfc5d]
Security context: 0x15e43ec9d9f1 <JSObject>
    1: _send [0x341e57da61] [internal/child_process.js:751] [bytecode=0x341e52b611 offset=655](this=0x14b237e828c9 <ChildProcess map = 0xc725fc75251>,0x14b237e827a9 <JSArray[4]>,0x20a7176025b1 <undefined>,0x14b237e828a1 <Object map = 0xc725fc74a31>,0x20a7176025b1 <undefined>)
    2: send [0x341e57da21] [internal/child_process.js:650] [bytecode=0x341e52ad51 o...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x95bd00 node::Abort() [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 2: 0x95cc46 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 3: 0xb3dbde v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 4: 0xb3de14 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 5: 0xf3ce52  [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 6: 0xf4cf5f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 7: 0xf16175  [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 8: 0xf1da3b v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
 9: 0x106ad58 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
10: 0xb3b96b v8::internal::String::Flatten(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
11: 0xb47a69 v8::String::Utf8Length(v8::Isolate*) const [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
12: 0xa09e61 node::StringBytes::Size(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, node::encoding) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
13: 0xa01b34 int node::StreamBase::WriteString<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
14: 0xa027ae void node::StreamBase::JSMethod<&(int node::StreamBase::WriteString<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
15: 0xbc6d2a  [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
16: 0xbc78d9 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a]
17: 0x2cf31bbcfc5d 
/home/vsts/work/_temp/daaf5f9e-acef-4cdd-9f33-cda1e20befa4.sh: line 5:  3632 Aborted                 (core dumped) ng build --output-path=/home/vsts/work/1/a
##[error]Bash exited with code '134'.
##[section]Finishing: npm install and build
```

thanks in advance.
In local build I am getting only this warring else all works fine.

```
WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial. Budget 10 MB was exceeded by 407 kB.
```

Comment: This GitHub issue may help: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618

Answer (score 0):

I set your angular.json

```
"build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 'node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng' build --prod ",
```

and build by `yarn build-prod` - works fine.